# How to profile a Gurobi execution? Both with a multi-thread setting and a distributed system

Tags: multithreading, distributed, profile, gurobi

I have an installation of Gurobi on a distributed system.

1. Is it possible to profile a distributed execution?
2. Is it possible to profile a multi thread execution (single node)?

Should I use callback functions or there exist other ways to do that for the two cases?

Comment: If you don’t get an answer here, you might want to try asking on [or.se].

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Thank you for your suggestion, I will try there.